# Variable declared in Public Function showing undefined

Tags: php

I've a super simple script here but I keep getting variable undefined as a warning any tips on how I can have this script run without error and do the same thing.

```
 class person{
          public $integer=4; 
          public $name;
          public function __construct($name){
             $this->name = $name;
          }
          public function pre(){
              return "pre message";
          }
          public function after($name){
              return "post message".$name;
          }
        };
        $person1 = new person($name="jason");
        $person2 = new person($name="bourne");
        echo $person1->pre();
        echo $person2->after();
```

Comment: `$dog1` and `$dog2` are undefined... Use [a good IDE](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-ide-2014-survey-results/) to see problems in your code as you type it, and you will avoid problems like this.

Comment: sorry forgot to change $dog1/2 in this code sample but it is changed locally and adding $person1->after($this->name); is returning Fatal error: Using $this when not in object

Comment: also the undefined variable is being listed as $name in after function

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the objects as `$person1` and `$person2`, but calling them as `$dog1` and `$dog2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to construct your new objects just passing the desired parameter, not an assigment:

```
    $person1 = new person("jason");
    $person2 = new person("bourne");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any arguments to `after` in `$dog2->after();`. Thus, `$name` is undefined in that method. If you want to use the class property `$name`, use `$this->name` there.

Also, as @MichaelKing pointed out, you are referring to `$dog1` and `$dog2`, but setting the variables as `$person1` and `$person2`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the objects as $person1 and $person2 so it means
that You have to use it like 
    echo $person1->pre();
    echo $person2->after();

Answer (score 0):

You create object for the class `person` as `$person1` and `$person2`. But you call the functions  using `$dog1` and `$dog2`, which is not declared or defined.